# Recover or develop lost main.storyboard file

Tags: ios, xcode

In iOS project my Main.storyboard file is accidentally deleted. I cant recover that as it is deleted from trash as well. I have all other interface and implementation class files. Is there any way to recover it??? Or if I have to develop it what should be my approach. Thank you.

Comment: You should really start using a SCM system like Git, even if you are only using it locally.

Answer (score 0):

1 - There is a place in Derived Data with following path:

```
/Users/<Your user name>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<Your App Name>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<app Name.app>
Browse to that location.
```

2 - On your .app file, right click -> Show Package Contents.

3 - In resulting directory list, browse the folder Base.lproj. Under that you are likely to find your old storyboard.

If you have done Delete Derived Data from XCode organizer, you are not likely to find anything up here. But fortunately, XCode doesn't delete it twice against your own wishes. So try your luck.

Comment: storyboards are compiled though,, no!?